# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'hasPermission')

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

I am back again with again my ticket function. This time I am working on a close command. Whatever I try I always come back at the same errors:

```
TypeError: message.member.hasPermission is not a function
```

Anyone who can look at the code?

```
    const { MessageEmbed, Collection, Permissions } = require ('discord.js');

module.exports = {
    name: 'close',
    description: "closes the ticket",
    execute(message, args, client){
        if(!message.member.hasPermission("MANAGE_CHANNELS")) return message.channel.send("Only a moderator can end a ticket!")

        if(message.member.hasPermission("MANAGE_CHANNELS")) message.channel.delete()
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you include the script that calls the `execute` method ?

Comment: try {
  command.execute(message, args, client);
 } catch (error) {
  console.error(error);
  message.channel.send('There was an error trying to execute that command!');
 }

Comment: *Don't* completely change your question. Mark an answer as "answering" (or add your own). Then write a new question with the appropriate details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this code will check if the member has the permission to `MANAGE_CHANNELS` and since `.permissions.has()` returns a boolean, it will either return true or false, if the user doesn't have such permission it will return a message that they cannot use the command, else if it will delete the channel...

```
if(!message.member.permissions.has(Permissions.FLAGS.MANAGE_CHANNELS)) { 
  return message.channel.send("Only a moderator can end a ticket!")
} else {
  return message.channel.delete()
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you should try reading the [docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/GuildMember) and see what properties GuildMember actually has, just a quick look through it, you should be able to find a `.permissions`, following from that, you'll get to this [doc](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/Permissions) on the Permissions class. From there, you can see you can use the `.has` function. So your final code should be

```js
message.member.permissions.has(Permissions.FLAGS.MANAGE_MESSAGES)
```

Comment: Found that one too! But I need to find a way to set it to false.

Comment: @Floris076 set what to false? remove the permission from the user or check if they dont have the permission, judging by your answer it'd be the second one, so you'd just add a ! to the start, so `if(!message.member.permissions.has(Permissions.FLAGS.MANAGE_MESSAGES) {}`

Answer (score 0):

Following your answer to my comment, it seems that you just put the arguments in the wrong order.

Your function is defined as

```
execute(client, message, args)
```

So you should call it with the arguments in the same order:

```
try {
  command.execute(client, message, args); // `client` is first, not last
} catch (error) {
  console.error(error);
  message.channel.send('There was an error trying to execute that command!');
}
```

Following your comment on this answer, it fixed the initial issue. Now `message.member` has a value!

But now `member.hasPermission` does not seem to be a function. And indeed it is not: when you look [at the documentation](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/GuildMember), there is no `hasPermission` method on a GuildMember.

So you have to figure out what exactly you need and look at the documentation to understand how to do it.

Comment: Already tried that, The error I get than is: TypeError: message.member.hasPermission is not a function

Comment: @Floris076 well then we're getting somewhere! I edited my answer to follow up on your new problem

Comment: I found how I need to set that he can do it, but I can't seem to find how he can't find it.